# Convert date column in MYSQL to different format

Tags: mysql

I need to update column pubDate_Date to 2018-02-04 20:39:55 from column pubDate with format Sun, 04 Feb 2018 20:39:55 +0100.

I have tried the following, but without success:

```
UPDATE `feeds` SET `pubDate_Date` = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(`pubDate`))
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
UPDATE feeds SET pubDate_Date = STR_TO_DATE(pubDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %T')
```

However there's no format code for timezone offsets, which MySQL will therefore *ignore* from the end of your original string (instead interpreting each string to be in the session's [`time_zone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone)).  Therefore:

- If all records are in the same timezone, you could simply do `SET time_zone = '+01:00'` before the above update command.
- Otherwise, do the following instead to adjust each time to the intended timezone:

  ```
  UPDATE feeds SET pubDate_Date = CONVERT_TZ(
    STR_TO_DATE(pubDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %T'),
    @@session.time_zone,
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(pubDate, -5, 3), ':', RIGHT(pubDate, 2)
  )
  ```

Comment: Thanks Eggyal, worked like a charm, I did not need the time zone adjustment.